# Find software package and version given a process/pid programatically

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

When I look at the rpm packages and grep for ssh, I get the following, but how do I programmatically know that ssh is from package openssh?

```
[root@vm ~]# rpm -qa | grep ssh
openssh-clients-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
libssh2-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64
sshpass-1.06-2.el7.x86_64
openssh-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
```

If run the following command, I see it is OpenSSH

```
[root@vm ~]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

But for ssh daemon, if I run version command, it returns a non-zero exit status because of unknown option `V`

```
[root@vm ~]# sshd -V
unknown option -- V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
            [-h host_key_file] [-o option] [-p port] [-u len]
```

**I want to automate the process of finding the software version given a process(pid) or service or daemon. What is an elegant way?**

Comment: `rpm -q --whatprovides $(type -p sshd)` or to isolate only the package name, `rpm -q --whatprovides $(type -p sshd) | cut -d'-' -f1`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Also is there any way I can programmatically know that all these OpenSSH belong to the same family?
`openssh-clients 7.4p1 21.el7 x86_64 
openssh 7.4p1 21.el7 x86_64 
openssh-server 7.4p1 21.el7 x86_64 
`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you asking there, but `rpm -qa | grep '^openssh'` will list all packages that begin with `openssh` allowing a quick comparison.

Comment: I was asking about SOURCERPM

Comment: How rpms are split into subpackages is not consistent across distributions. There the best you can do is find out which package an executable belongs to. Then all you can do is check the `.spec` file for the base package to determine if, and how, it is split into subpackages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/sbin/sshd
```

If you have the $PID:

```
rpm -qf $(ps af | grep $PID | awk '{print $5}')
```